# Recursively create directories prior to opening file for writing

Tags: python, directory

I need to write to a file (truncating) and the path it is on itself might not exist). For example, I want to write to `/tmp/a/b/c/config`, but `/tmp/a` itself might not exist. Then, `open('/tmp/a/b/c/config', 'w')` would not work, obviously, since it doesn't make the necessary directories. However, I can work with the following code:

```
import os

config_value = 'Foo=Bar'  # Temporary placeholder

config_dir = '/tmp/a/b/c'  # Temporary placeholder
config_file_path = os.path.join(config_dir, 'config')

if not os.path.exists(config_dir):
    os.makedirs(config_dir)

with open(config_file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(config_value)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this? Both Python 2.x and Python 3.x would be nice to know (even though I use 2.x in my code, due to dependency reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're repeating this pattern in multiple places, you could create your own Context Manager that extends `open()` and overloads `__enter__()`:

```
import os

class OpenCreateDirs(open):
    def __enter__(self, filename, *args, **kwargs):
        file_dir = os.path.dirname(filename)
        if not os.path.exists(file_dir):
            os.makedirs(file_dir)

        super(OpenCreateDirs, self).__enter__(filename, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then your code becomes:

```
import os

config_value = 'Foo=Bar'  # Temporary placeholder
config_file_path = os.path.join('/tmp/a/b/c', 'config')

with OpenCreateDirs(config_file_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(config_value)
```

The first method to be called when you run `with open(...) as f:` is `open.__enter__()`. So by creating directories before calling `super(...).__enter__()`, you create the directories before attempting to open the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)
Well, this was a one-off thing (in the current scenario) and I felt it was a common pattern for a lot of people, which is why I asked in the first place. However, the fact that I could use a Context Manager helps me out a lot in the long run.