# Create directory in Pillow if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a script that takes images and saves them into directories based on specific user ids. Those directories don't yet exist. For example:

media/1/ex.jpg
media/2/ex.jpg
.
.
.

When I run my script, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

However, when I create a directory, for example (1), and run it, it'll save the image in the 1 directory. Is there a way for Pillow to be able to create directories if they don't exist?

Comment: No. **PIL** is an imaging library, not a file management tool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively create directories prior to opening file for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711216/recursively-create-directories-prior-to-opening-file-for-writing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with basic python. This example assumes that 'media' already exists, and it is in the same directory that your script is running from.

```
from os import mkdir, path, getcwd

def get_subdirectory(sd):
    dir = path.join(getcwd(), f'media/{sd}')
    if not path.isdir(dir):
        mkdir(dir)
    return dir
    
#image save example
#image.save(f"{get_subdirectory('1')}/ex.jpg")
```